# How to Add custom markers to a google directions map at the start only of multiple journeys

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Firstly let me say I am not a Java or even web developer. I have pieced together this code via the web and am almost at the finish point - but cannot get over the line.

I am mapping journeys for a trucking firm, and want to use a custom marker at the start of each journey, with no marker at the end of the journey. The attached code does all I need for mapping the journey but I can't get the markers to render on the page.  What am I missing?

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var num, map, data;
var requestArray = [],
    renderArray = [];

// A JSON Array containing some people/routes and the destinations/stops
var jsonArray = {
    "Journey1": ["-38.076600, 176.722100", "-38.279641, 175.897505"],
        "Journey2": ["-38.279641, 175.897505", "-38.058217, 175.783939"],
        "Journey3": ["-38.058217, 175.783939", "-37.964919, 175.478964"],
        "Journey4": ["-37.964919, 175.478964", "-38.323678, 175.152163"],
        "Journey5": ["-38.323678, 175.152163", "-38.274879, 175.894551"],
        "Journey6": ["-38.274879, 175.894551", "-38.095284, 176.076530"],
        "Journey7": ["-38.095284, 176.076530", "-38.075316, 176.716276"],
        "Journey8": ["-38.075316, 176.716276", "-38.076600, 176.722100"]
}

// 16 Standard Colours for navigation polylines
var colourArray = ['Maroon', 'Green', 'Olive', 'DarkBlue', 'Violet', 'Teal', 'Gray', 'Silver'];
var Labelarray = [
    'Kawerau Depot, Ex: CHH Kawerau - Cogen Plant Kinleith - Hogfuel - CHH KINLEITH',
    'Cogen Plant Kinleith - TD Haulage Pinedale - Empty',
    'TD Haulage Pinedale - Gascoigne Farms Cambridge - Post Peeling - Untreated - GASCOIGNE FARMS LTD',
    'Gascoigne Farms Cambridge - Tregoweth Te Kuiti - Empty',
    'Tregoweth Te Kuiti - CHH Kinleith - Chip - FLL NETLOGIX LTD',
    'CHH Kinleith - Mamaku Sawmill Mamaku - Empty',
    'Mamaku Sawmill Mamaku - CHH Kawerau - Chip - FLL NETLOGIX LTD',
    'CHH Kawerau - Kawerau Depot - Empty'];


// Let's make an array of requests which will become individual polylines on the map.
function generateRequests() {
    requestArray = [];

    for (var route in jsonArray) {
        // This now deals with one of the people / routes

        // Somewhere to store the wayoints
        var waypts = [];

        // 'start' and 'finish' will be the routes origin and destination
        var start, finish

        // lastpoint is used to ensure that duplicate waypoints are stripped
        var lastpoint

        data = jsonArray[route]
        limit = data.length
        for (var waypoint = 0; waypoint < limit; waypoint++) {
            if (data[waypoint] === lastpoint) {
                // Duplicate of of the last waypoint - don't bother
                //  continue;
            }
            // Prepare the lastpoint for the next loop
            lastpoint = data[waypoint]
            // Add this to waypoint to the array for making the request
            waypts.push({
                location: data[waypoint],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        // Grab the first waypoint for the 'start' location
        start = (waypts.shift()).location;
        // Grab the last waypoint for use as a 'finish' location
        finish = waypts.pop();
        if (finish === undefined) {
            // Unless there was no finish location for some reason?
            finish = start;
        } else {
            finish = finish.location;
        }
        // Let's create the Google Maps request object
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: finish,
            waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        // and save it in our requestArray
        requestArray.push({
            "route": route,
            "request": request
        });
    }
    processRequests();
}

function processRequests() {
    // Counter to track request submission and process one at a time;
    var i = 0;
    // Determines if we will use an image for the icon 1 = true, 0 = false
    var UseImage = 1;
    var j = 0;
    var x = 0;
    // Used to submit the request 'i'
    function submitRequest() {
        directionsService.route(requestArray[i].request, directionResults);
    }
    // Used as callback for the above request for current 'i'
    function directionResults(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            j++;

            //j = i + 1
            // Create a unique DirectionsRenderer 'i'
            renderArray[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: true
            });
            renderArray[i].setMap(map);

            renderArray[i].setOptions({
                preserveViewport: true,
                suppressInfoWindows: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeColor: colourArray[i]
                }
            });
            //**************************************
            // this is the code I am trying to add in so that I get a marker only at the start position of the line.                                      
            // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };
            // Add markers to the map
            var image = {
                url: "Marker Green " + j + ".png",
                // This marker is 27 pixels wide by 40 pixels tall.
                size: new google.maps.Size(27, 40),
                // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                // The anchor for this image is the base of the icon at 14, 39.
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(14, 39)
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(requestArray[i].request.origin),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: Labelarray[i] + ' - ' + requestArray[i].request.origin,
                zIndex: i

            });
            //**************************************
            //end of code I am trying to get to work       
        }



        // Use this new renderer with the result
        renderArray[i].setDirections(result);

        // and start the next request
        nextRequest();
    }

    function nextRequest() {
        // Increase the counter
        i++;
        // Make sure we are still waiting for a request
        if (i >= requestArray.length) {
            // No more to do
            return;
        }
        // Submit another request
        submitRequest();
    }
    // This request is just to kick start the whole process
    submitRequest();
}

// Called Onload
function init() {
    // Some basic map setup (from the API docs) //Map centre
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.143567, 175.965254),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    // Start the request making
    generateRequests()
}
// Get the ball rolling and trigger our init() on 'load'
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the url of your image? `url: "Marker Green " + j + ".png"` - Have you tried renaming your image without spaces? For example: `marker_green_xxx.png`

Comment: Also the image url should be a relative path from your script location to the image location. If, for example, your image is in a folder called `images`, the url should be `url: "images/marker_green_" + j + ".png"`.

Comment: *It has now been resolved* - this will not help anyone understand what you did and how you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`requestArray[i].request.origin` is a string containing 2 numbers.  The google.maps.LatLng constructor expects two numbers.

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(requestArray[i].request.origin),
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: Labelarray[i] + ' - ' + requestArray[i].request.origin,
            zIndex: i

        });
```

You need to either save that as a google.maps.LatLng object or parse the numbers out of the string to construct the google.maps.LatLng object:

```
        var coords = requestArray[i].request.origin.split(",");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: Labelarray[i] + ' - ' + requestArray[i].request.origin,
            zIndex: i

        });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw3mE/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var num, map, data;
var requestArray = [],
    renderArray = [];

// A JSON Array containing some people/routes and the destinations/stops
var jsonArray = {
    "Journey1": ["-38.076600, 176.722100", "-38.279641, 175.897505"],
        "Journey2": ["-38.279641, 175.897505", "-38.058217, 175.783939"],
        "Journey3": ["-38.058217, 175.783939", "-37.964919, 175.478964"],
        "Journey4": ["-37.964919, 175.478964", "-38.323678, 175.152163"],
        "Journey5": ["-38.323678, 175.152163", "-38.274879, 175.894551"],
        "Journey6": ["-38.274879, 175.894551", "-38.095284, 176.076530"],
        "Journey7": ["-38.095284, 176.076530", "-38.075316, 176.716276"],
        "Journey8": ["-38.075316, 176.716276", "-38.076600, 176.722100"]
}

// 16 Standard Colours for navigation polylines
var colourArray = ['Maroon', 'Green', 'Olive', 'DarkBlue', 'Violet', 'Teal', 'Gray', 'Silver'];
var Labelarray = [
    'Kawerau Depot, Ex: CHH Kawerau - Cogen Plant Kinleith - Hogfuel - CHH KINLEITH',
    'Cogen Plant Kinleith - TD Haulage Pinedale - Empty',
    'TD Haulage Pinedale - Gascoigne Farms Cambridge - Post Peeling - Untreated - GASCOIGNE FARMS LTD',
    'Gascoigne Farms Cambridge - Tregoweth Te Kuiti - Empty',
    'Tregoweth Te Kuiti - CHH Kinleith - Chip - FLL NETLOGIX LTD',
    'CHH Kinleith - Mamaku Sawmill Mamaku - Empty',
    'Mamaku Sawmill Mamaku - CHH Kawerau - Chip - FLL NETLOGIX LTD',
    'CHH Kawerau - Kawerau Depot - Empty'];


// Let's make an array of requests which will become individual polylines on the map.
function generateRequests() {
    requestArray = [];

    for (var route in jsonArray) {
        // This now deals with one of the people / routes

        // Somewhere to store the wayoints
        var waypts = [];

        // 'start' and 'finish' will be the routes origin and destination
        var start, finish

        // lastpoint is used to ensure that duplicate waypoints are stripped
        var lastpoint

        data = jsonArray[route]
        limit = data.length
        for (var waypoint = 0; waypoint < limit; waypoint++) {
            if (data[waypoint] === lastpoint) {
                // Duplicate of of the last waypoint - don't bother
                //  continue;
            }
            // Prepare the lastpoint for the next loop
            lastpoint = data[waypoint]
            // Add this to waypoint to the array for making the request
            waypts.push({
                location: data[waypoint],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        // Grab the first waypoint for the 'start' location
        start = (waypts.shift()).location;
        // Grab the last waypoint for use as a 'finish' location
        finish = waypts.pop();
        if (finish === undefined) {
            // Unless there was no finish location for some reason?
            finish = start;
        } else {
            finish = finish.location;
        }
        // Let's create the Google Maps request object
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: finish,
            waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        // and save it in our requestArray
        requestArray.push({
            "route": route,
            "request": request
        });
    }
    processRequests();
}

function processRequests() {
    // Counter to track request submission and process one at a time;
    var i = 0;
    // Determines if we will use an image for the icon 1 = true, 0 = false
    var UseImage = 1;
    var j = 0;
    var x = 0;
    // Used to submit the request 'i'
    function submitRequest() {
        directionsService.route(requestArray[i].request, directionResults);
    }
    // Used as callback for the above request for current 'i'
    function directionResults(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            j++;

            //j = i + 1
            // Create a unique DirectionsRenderer 'i'
            renderArray[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: true
            });
            renderArray[i].setMap(map);

            renderArray[i].setOptions({
                preserveViewport: true,
                suppressInfoWindows: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeColor: colourArray[i]
                }
            });
            // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };
            // Add markers to the map
            var image = {
                url: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+i+"%7C0000FF",
                // This marker is 27 pixels wide by 40 pixels tall.
                size: new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                // The anchor for this image is the base of the icon at 14, 39.
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(10.5, 34)
            };
            var coords = requestArray[i].request.origin.split(",");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: Labelarray[i] + ' - ' + requestArray[i].request.origin,
                zIndex: i

            });
        }



        // Use this new renderer with the result
        renderArray[i].setDirections(result);

        // and start the next request
        nextRequest();
    }

    function nextRequest() {
        // Increase the counter
        i++;
        // Make sure we are still waiting for a request
        if (i >= requestArray.length) {
            // No more to do
            return;
        }
        // Submit another request
        submitRequest();
    }
    // This request is just to kick start the whole process
    submitRequest();
}

// Called Onload
function init() {
    // Some basic map setup (from the API docs) //Map centre
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.143567, 175.965254),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    // Start the request making
    generateRequests()
}
// Get the ball rolling and trigger our init() on 'load'
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```